# Why am I getting an undefined method '<=' for in my ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Question I have a custom divide and conquer array sorter that I would like to use. This all works well until I try to use it on an array in my controller I get this message.. `NoMethodError (undefined method '<=' for #<Entry:0x0000000ac7d850>)`: Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

here is my Entry model with the mergesort method I am calling in my controller.

```
def self.mergesort(container)
  return container if (container.size <= 1)
  mid   = container.size / 2
  left  = container[0...mid]
  right = container[mid...container.size]
  merge(mergesort(left), mergesort(right))
end

def self.merge(left, right)
  sorted = []
  until left.empty? or right.empty?
    (left.first <= right.first) ? sorted << left.shift : sorted << right.shift
  end
  sorted + left + right
end
```

Here is my Entry controller where I am trying to call it.

```
  def pending_sort 
    @ent_sort = Entry.where("section = ? and approve_disapprove = ?", @mgr_section, '3')


    @ent = Entry.mergesort(@ent_sort)

  end
```

Comment: What are the elements in the left array? Are these Entry objects?

Comment: What is after the `#` in your error message?

Comment: left.first is returning an object that doesn't have a `<=` method (for example `nil`). What does left contain?

Comment: Maybe that's because you are sorting an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, not an `Array`?

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `<=' for # what exactly!)

Comment: Try call `to_a` right after `where` to force loading data from database, then sort the resulting array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `nil` for the first element of either `left` or `right`.

```
irb(main):001:0> left = []
  => []
irb(main):002:0> right = [1]
  => [1]
irb(main):003:0> left.first
  => nil
irb(main):004:0> left.first <= right.first
  NoMethodError: undefined method `<=' for nil:NilClass
  from (irb):4
  from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

You can fix the error by casting the `nil` to a different value. For example, if the values you are comparing are always integers you can change the following line:

```
(left.first <= right.first) ? sorted << left.shift : sorted << right.shift
```

to this:

```
(left.first.to_i <= right.first.to_i) ? sorted << left.shift : sorted << right.shift
```

But think about how it will affect your functionality... it may break something if it isn't what you actually want to do.